# Hardcoded byte array ends up as data when it exceeds 0xF in length

Tags: c++11, gcc, clang, c++14, llvm

My goal is to have my `.rdata` sections to contain as less stuff as possible and let the compiler use the text/code sections whenever it can. Right now I have a small issue which I hope someone could help me with. In clang and GCC, when you would compile the following C++ code (note the array is 15 bytes in length):

```
#include <windows.h>

void _start() {
  unsigned char bytes[] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF};
  MessageBoxA(nullptr, (char*)bytes, "Hi", MB_OK);
}
```

This compiles as I would want it to. All hardcoded data is nicely embedded into the code itself (it uses immediate movs) and so nothing is added to any data sections, no references to any data section is made. Here is the IDA PRO decompilation:
[image]

If you would add another byte to the array and have it exceed the 15 bytes in length (16 bytes in length totally now), like so:

```
#include <windows.h>

void _start() {
  unsigned char bytes[] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10};
  MessageBoxA(nullptr, (char*)bytes, "Hi", MB_OK);
}
```

Then the compiler behaves in a way I want to get rid of. That is that it doesn't embed it anymore in the code, but instead moves everything inside the data section (the `unk_100402000`, which is inside `.rdata`):

[image]

I tested this code against multiple compilers. MSVC embed these hardcoded byte arrays always nicely in the code itself, no matter how long it is. Since I would really like to keep using Clang and GCC, I hope there is a solution to this.

The reason I need to limit usage of the `.rdata` section, is that I am doing an experimental project where any reference or access outside the text/code section will result in a major performance hit. Around 1000x slower per access outside text/code section. Because of this, I really need to have the compiler use the text/code section as much as possible.

#### Question

How can I make Clang/GCC compile 15+ long hardcoded byte arrays so that it uses immediate mov operations on the stack instead of using the `.rdata` section? If it is not possible through compiler options, could it be possible to change this behaviour through a compiler pass? I am also fine with any dirty hacks I need to apply to Clang in order to make this work.

I know I could split my longer byte arrays up into smaller individual ones, but this is not the solution I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Clang version: 4.0.1

### Best solution for now

As you can see in the following image. The big hardcoded byte array is compiled as multiple immediate mov instructions on the stack and so never references anything from a data section. This is exactly what I am looking for. Are there multiple ways to achieve this same behaviour?

[image]

Comment: Why are you so worried about keeping the data out of the `.data` section?

Comment: @Sean I am working on a project where I experiment with hardware virtualization and EPT. In the best case I would like all read-only data to be embedded in the code section, so that I have less ept violations happening inside my project and so performance increases greatly for me. The moment code starts reading some data within its image space, an ept violation happens for me and a lot of cpu cycles get lost. My goal is to make this as less as possible. Technically shouldn't all read-only data be able to be embedded as code?

Comment: @SteffenBrem - the problem with embedding it in the code section is that it then becomes possible to execute the data, which is probably now what you want. If it is placed in a non-execute segment then this won't be possible.

Comment: @Sean I understand. In most cases it would be preferable. For me this is not a downside at all, so it is not an issue in my case. It is very important for me that as much data as possible is generated as code and not as data. You believe it is achievable to make clang prefer code over data section?

Comment: Note: `gcc -O2` performs a similar trick (64bit immediate values) upto about 96+1chars;

Comment: Why is it different having it in the data segment or having it on the stack as your first example implies?

Comment: @Surt Because data references are costly in my case and code execution is not. So when the value is build up from the code and stored in the stack, it evades the data section completely and performance is greatly increased in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can afford the performance penalty, something like this seems to work on clang; in my tests, it compiles to a set of immediate mov's ( gcc works too after fixing the attribute ):

```
template <unsigned char C>
struct noopt { [[clang::optnone]] unsigned char operator()() const { return C; } };

#define NODATA(v) (noopt<(v)>{}())

int main(){
    unsigned char bytes[] = { NODATA(0x1), NODATA(0x2), NODATA(0x3), NODATA(0x4), };

    // ...
}
```

this has also the bonus of working everywhere ( not just in array declarations ).

Comment: This is interesting. It does indeed force to compile EXACTLY how I would want it to be: https://gyazo.com/7ffdb2c35b250b93d551fa232e536959

Really curious what parts of Clang would cause this and if it would be possible to let clang always prefer this way of compiling.

Comment: @SteffenBrem moreover, note that inlined calls like `foo(arg,const0,const1,...)` may end up with those consts stored in text or data section; using NODATA() works with these as well

Comment: Why not `template<unsigned char c> noopt<c> nodata{};`, then `nodata<0x1>`, does that not work?

Comment: @Yakk do you mean `nodata<0x01>()` ? or by replacing operator() with a conversion operator ? yes, I think that's the same ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I mean, get rid of macro and use a template variable.  With the general rule that, all things being equal, don't use a macro.

Comment: @Yakk agreed, but there are different ways of doing it ( after all, the OP didn't specify which c++ he were targeting ) and my intent was just to show the undelying idea. The macro is there just for expository purposes.

Comment: @Yakk, actually, note that the non macro version is not equivalent because it seems clang::optnone tends to propagate to the full expression as far as I can see ( that is, the resulting asm is different adding more overhead than strictly needed )...

Answer (score 2):

If data is static ( not local to function scope ), you can do the following:

```
 void Check( unsigned const char* x);

 void Do() {
   static const unsigned char bytes[] __attribute__((section(".text"))) =
   {
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
       0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10
   };
   Check( bytes );
 }

 int main()
 {
     Do();
 }
```

which ends up in:

```
Disassembly of section .text:
     08048580 <Do()>:
  8048580:  83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
  8048583:  68 a0 85 04 08          push   $0x80485a0
  8048588:  e8 e3 ff ff ff          call   8048570 <Check(unsigned char const*)>
  804858d:  83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
  8048590:  c3                      ret

  ... much other disassembled code follows ...

 080485a0 <Do()::bytes>:
  80485a0:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  80485b0:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  80485c0:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  80485d0:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  80485e0:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  80485f0:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  8048600:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
  8048610:  01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f 10     ................
```

All is only in .text section.

If data must be local, you can simply copy manually by using:

```
void Check( unsigned const char* x); 

template< typename IN, typename OUT, unsigned int size >
void Cpy( IN (&in)[size], OUT (&out)[size] )
{   
    static_assert( sizeof( IN) == sizeof( OUT ) );
    memcpy( out, in, size * sizeof(OUT) );
}   

void Do() {
  static const unsigned char static_bytes[] __attribute__((section(".text"))) = 
  {   
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10,
      0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF, 0x10
  };  

  unsigned char bytes[ sizeof( static_bytes )]; 
  Cpy( static_bytes, bytes );


  Check( bytes );
}   

int main()
{   
    Do();
}
```

Everything is still in the .text section, but you must copy the data yourself to the local context. I was not able to force the compiler itself to do that.

Comment: @cmaster: you are right in the point that array elements can be sizeof != 1, fiixed that. Thanks! But you are not right in the point of needed static assert for != sizes. The template check for that, because size of in and out must be the same!

Comment: Thanks for answering. But moving the data from `.rdata` to `.text` is not eliminating the problem for me. It would still deref and issue a read operation on the CPU, causing a 1000x slower performance hit. @Massimiliano Janes example shows nicely how I want the compiler to behave. The data should be literally converted to code and use the stack instead of storing it inside some image section.

Comment: @SteffenBrem:Quite unclear what you really want! The "data" is part of text section now and you wrote " any reference or access outside the text/code section will result... ". The access is now inside the text section, so I do not can't catch the point!?

Comment: @cmaster: Ubs, you are right. In hope my fix is now OK.;)

Comment: Yep, it's ok now. I removed my comments.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following on multiple versions of gcc and clang using compiler explorer and it seems to work.

The `cout` is just to prevent the compiler from optimizing this to nop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void f(int num) {
    char r0[15] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    char r1[15] = {1,2,9,4,5,6,7,3,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};
    char r2[14] = {3,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};

    char r[44];

    std::memcpy(r, r0, 15);
    std::memcpy(r + 15, r1, 15);
    std::memcpy(r + 30, r2, 14);

    std::cout << r;
}
```